# Can a trait be passed as a Fn reference or closure

Tags: rust, function-pointers, traits

In rust, you can take in a reference to a `Fn` as [documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#taking-closures-as-arguments):

```
fn call_with_one(some_closure: &Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    some_closure(1)
}
let answer = call_with_one(&|x| x + 2);
```

However I want to write a trait that, if implemented, the Runnable can be passed to anything that expects a `Fn()`. Is this possible?

```
trait Runnable {
    fn run(&self);
}

struct MyRunnable;
impl Runnable for MyRunnable {
    fn run(&self) {}
}

struct StructThatTakesClosure<'life> {
    closure_field: &'life Fn(),
}

fn main() {
    // is there a way to change the Runnable trait to automatically match the
    // Fn() interface such that the MyRunnable instance can be passed directly?
    StructThatTakesClosure { closure_field: &|| MyRunnable.run() };
}
```

I have tried implementing the 3 normally `extern` calls as default functions but I didn't manage to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible on stable Rust, because the exact [definition of the `Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) trait is unstable.

On nightly Rust you can implement the `Fn` traits, but only for concrete types, so it's not very helpful.

```
impl<'a> std::ops::Fn<()> for MyRunnable {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, ():()) {
        self.run();
    }
}
```